# Green line in captured video(AVCaptureSession)

Tags: ios, h.264, video-capture, avcapturesession, xcode9

We got a problem after building application with Xcode 9:

When we capture video on iPhone 7 got green line in the right of video.
Here is link to frame from video - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tq7Do.jpg

This green line have 16px width.
We used coder - "h264" and AVCaptureSession for capturing.

For testing, we made video sizes value dividable by 16, but it did not solve the problem.
We have already submitted application on AppStore from Xcode 8, and all videos does not have any broken pixels. The code was not changed.

I tested on my iPad mini 4, and does no have this problems. But client got problems on iPhone 7, I do not have this device so I'm not able to debug this.

Comment: Verify that you use the correct stride values. (Which may be larger than the width)

Comment: Have you found any solution for this? as I am facing the same issue

Comment: @Khush Unfortunately, I stopped working on that project year ago and can`t say that we found the true solution. 
I just can say about a quick fix: According to observations, we noticed that the green line takes exactly 16 pixels, and based on this, we cut the video by 16 pixels. In the application, we had functionality that the video was cut off to a square, so no noticeable changes were made to the user. 

But, I am sure that it's not the best solution, and may work only as a quick fix.

Comment: @shshsh Okay, Thank you.!

Answer (score 1):

The encoder requires the width and height of the content to be divisible by 2, try that instead of 16. You may only see the green line on devices where the width would be an odd number, such as an iPhone 6 or iPhone X.